# How can I find out how big my Meteor app is?

Tags: meteor

I'd like to know the amount of data that is going over the wire when someone is first opening my Meteor app.

[Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt) is useful but I'd like something I can run locally on my own machine.

Ideally I'd also like to see a breakdown per package so I can decide on whether I want to keep or ditch a specific package.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use your browser's developer tools. For example, in Chrome, open the developer tools (right click -> Inspect Element) and go to the network tab. Refresh and you'll see all of the javascript files and their sizes, one per package. You can filter for only Scripts and then sort by size (you may have to do a full refresh to clear out the cache for this to work). jQuery will probably be one of, if not the biggest package.

You can also run meteor with the --production flag and the server will send one concatenated and minified js file. This is much smaller than the total size of the individual package files, but shows you the actual size of the data that will be sent in production.

You also need to be aware of how much data you are publishing/subscribing. If you add the [`meteorhacks:fast-render`](https://github.com/meteorhacks/fast-render) package, the initial published set of data will be added as a script tag to the HTML. You should also be aware of how much data you are publishing while the user browses and uses your application. Something like [Kadira](https://kadira.io/) is helpful with that.